# UnicodeDecodeError in python-3.4

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, encoding, jupyter-notebook

I am using Python (3.4) in Jupyter Notebook, which by default should using utf-8 already. But I got the following error when reading some data from a csv file. Any idea how to fix this? Thanks!

Code read from a csv file:

```
with open('my_data.csv') as csvfile:
    line = csv.reader(csvfile)

    for row in line:
        print (row)
```

Error:

```
Last executed 2017-01-06 04:58:59 in 85ms
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-09c617346fbb> in <module>()
     14     line = csv.reader(csvfile)
     15 
---> 16     for row in line:
     17         print (row)

/usr/lib/python3.4/encodings/ascii.py in decode(self, input, final)
     24 class IncrementalDecoder(codecs.IncrementalDecoder):
     25     def decode(self, input, final=False):
---> 26         return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
     27 
     28 class StreamWriter(Codec,codecs.StreamWriter):

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xcc in position 2588: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify the encoding when opening the file.  Also per [csv module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html) use the `newline=''` option for the to-be-wrapped file:

```
with open('my_data.csv',encoding='utf8',newline='') as csvfile:
    line = csv.reader(csvfile)
```